# Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element for Spring web services

Tags: java, spring, xsd, spring-ws

I am brand new to Spring web services and I keep getting this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [annotation-driven]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml]
```

After some digging around, it looks like I most likely have a version mismatch between my schemas and jars but I do not see where (I'm shooting for v3.1).

Here is every **Spring** jar in my library:

```
M2_REPO\org\springframework\spring-aop\3.1.1.RELEASE\spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
M2_REPO\org\springframework\spring-asm\3.1.1.RELEASE\spring-asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
M2_REPO\org\springframework\spring-beans\3.1.1.RELEASE\spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
M2_REPO\org\springframework\spring-context\3.1.1.RELEASE\spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
M2_REPO\org\springframework\spring-context-support\3.1.1.RELEASE\spring-context-support-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
M2_REPO\org\springframework\spring-core\3.1.1.RELEASE\spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
M2_REPO\org\springframework\spring-expression\3.1.1.RELEASE\spring-expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
M2_REPO\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\3.1.1.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
M2_REPO\org\springframework\spring-jms\3.1.1.RELEASE\spring-jms-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
M2_REPO\org\springframework\spring-oxm\3.1.1.RELEASE\spring-oxm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
M2_REPO\org\springframework\ws\spring-oxm\1.5.10\spring-oxm-1.5.10.jar
M2_REPO\org\springframework\ws\spring-oxm-tiger\1.5.10\spring-oxm-tiger-1.5.10.jar
M2_REPO\org\springframework\security\spring-security-acl\3.1.1.RELEASE\spring-security-acl-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
M2_REPO\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\3.1.1.RELEASE\spring-security-config-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
M2_REPO\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\3.1.1.RELEASE\spring-security-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
M2_REPO\org\springframework\security\spring-security-remoting\3.1.1.RELEASE\spring-security-remoting-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
M2_REPO\org\springframework\security\spring-security-taglibs\3.1.1.RELEASE\spring-security-taglibs-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
M2_REPO\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\3.1.1.RELEASE\spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
M2_REPO\org\springframework\spring-test\3.1.1.RELEASE\spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
M2_REPO\org\springframework\spring-tx\3.1.1.RELEASE\spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
M2_REPO\org\springframework\spring-web\3.1.1.RELEASE\spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
M2_REPO\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\3.1.1.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
M2_REPO\org\springframework\ws\spring-ws-core\2.1.2.RELEASE\spring-ws-core-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar
M2_REPO\org\springframework\ws\spring-ws-core-tiger\1.5.10\spring-ws-core-tiger-1.5.10.jar
M2_REPO\org\springframework\ws\spring-xml\1.5.10\spring-xml-1.5.10.jar
```

**spring-ws-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="my.package"/>

    <sws:annotation-driven />

    <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="MyService"
        portTypeName="MyServiceInterface"
        locationUri="/myService/">
        <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/mySchema.xsd" />
    </sws:dynamic-wsdl>

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
         version="3.0">

    <display-name>
        My Webservice Created By Archetype for Spring WS
    </display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>          
        <init-param>
            <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**applicationContext.xml** I'm not sure that I even need this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="my.package" />

    <context:annotation-config />

</beans>
```

The error is being thrown in spring-ws-servlet.xml whenever it reads a  element. Like I said, I'm brand new to Spring web services and recognize that there is probably an obvious flaw in my setup and would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. Apparently one of my dependencies was bringing in a different version of spring-ws even though it wasn't listed under my referenced libraries. I actually ended up not needing the whole dependency so I simply removed it and now I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: Do you know which dependency it was? I have read your question yesterday (before your answer) and the only thing I could come up with on google was something similar.

Comment: Well, the dependency I removed was one written by my company so I can't really say for sure. I'm assuming since I still have some 3.0 spring jars in my library that it was just an older version of spring-ws.